# How can I remove items from an array having met specific conditions in-place?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I am working on what i thought is a simple algorithm:

> Task: Look at the given array, take only the even numbers and multiply them by 2.  The catch is to modify the array in its place and NOT create a new array.

I can loop/map through an array and figure out what numbers are even, so
I got this far:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

arr.forEach((x, y) => {
        if (x % 2 !== 0) {
           // I would like to splice those numbers, 
           // but can't figure out how to do it?
        } 
    })
```

Again, the catch is that modifying the original array is not allowed, returning 4, 8, 12, 16, and 20.

Comment: do you really need to take splice? what about looping from the end?

Comment: Yes, i apologize, i meant even numbers, that are divisible by 2.  Basically i was easily able to solve this problem when i could create a new array. I just mapped through it, then used if (x % 2 === 0) newArray.push(x *2). I basically need to do the same thing here but i can't create a new array to do this.

Comment: I do not need to use splice necessarily, this is just what came into my head. I figured i have to use splice since i need to modify the original array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good approach in my opinion, but if you insist on modifying the existing array without creating a new one, this should do the job:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

let i = 0;
while (i < arr.length) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
        arr[i] *= 2;
    } else {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
    i++;
}

console.log(arr.join(", "));
```

The i-- comes into play, because when you splice the current index (where the next element will be after the splice) and you execute i++, it's going to skip the current index. The same effect can possibly be achieved by adding i++ in the if block and remove the i-- in the else block.

Comment: Ah, this works!!!!!!!! Yes this is just an algorithm i was given, def not a solution to a problem. I was able to easily solve it by creating a new array.  I guess this was thinking outside the box type of problem? Thank you so much for this, im gonna go dissect it now.

Comment: If you have any questions about this algorithm please list them so I can upgrade the answer.

Comment: I understand everything, except why do you --i and then ++i ? As i understand it,  you while loop through the array, create if statement where if number is even you multiply it by 2. Now you need to get rid of odd numbers. Do you do this via splice.....basically if i = even then * 2, else splice it at current numer that is not even which is "i", and only by 1. How do i-- and i ++ come into play?

Comment: why not move `i++` into assigning block and omit `i--`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all.
Why would you do that? If you don't want the old array just take the new one.

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
const evenNumbers = arr.filter(item => item % 2 === 0)

Unless it's something required, explore all Js Array methods, always are multiple ways to get to an answer. Try to make your life easy.

Like the example before you will have the old and the new. Take wherever you need.

Comment: I had to solve it 2 ways, one by creating a new array which was easy, second way had to be by only modifying the original array. I would def not try to do this as my go to option. Thank you for your advice, def important to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a different approach and loop from start by using a new index for all items to keep and later adjust the length of the array.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

let l = 0; i = 0;

while (i < array.length) {
    console.log(...array);
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) array[l++] = array[i] * 2;
    i++;
}

array.length = l;

console.log(...array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes, O(n). This is how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Code:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

const result = arr
  .filter(n => n % 2 === 0)
  .map(n => n * 2)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Ah! I am not familiar with prototype yet, im going to go try to learn it learn about it right now. I was actually tasked with reading about it but after trying to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you had in mind?

```js
const arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

for (let i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--)
  if(arr[i]%2>0) arr.splice(i,1)
arr.forEach((v,i,a)=> a[i]=v*2)

console.log(arr);
```

As you want to remove elements from an array you are looping over, it is important that you start from the end and work your way down to `0` since going forward you would skip an element as soon as you remove one.

Comment: My array is only up to 10 though, not 20? I can't modify its length.

Comment: How do you expect to get a result vector with values of up to 20 if you don't multiply in the loop and you only go up to 10?

Comment: :D that can be easily.done ...

Comment: i apologize if i am not following. You can multiply,  as I understand it, you can't start with an array of 20. So basically if you were able to identify 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 as the numbers you need to multiply by 2 in the end, you can multiply then. To be honest im a little confused as far as directions myself at this point.